# Unable to achieve load testing on EJB subject using threading

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb, load-testing

I posted this question asking why 100000 `run`() calls is faster compred to  100000 `start`() as  i found out that despite multi threading, 100000 `start` would actually take longer than 10000 `run` calls because of the thread management.

Actually, i was trying to spawn 100000 threads to simulate a load on an EJB method i wish to test, and it seems not possible this way. Is there a way which i could achieve this? Or is it that i would need to have multiple machines in order to achieve that load.

Is it true that if i have a quad core pc, i should only spawn at most 4 threads at a time to prevent too heavy context switching because at any one time 4 threads would be run?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want to simulate. Do you want to call a certain EJB method (I suppose session bean) concurrently?

Comment: @home yes, i want to simulate 100 calls on an EJB method concurrently.

Comment: @Chin Boon, Why? What to you hope to achieve?  You cannot prove thread safety this way.

Comment: If you want a "near reality" test you need more than one client machine. Do not only think of threads but of IO as well. You may not need 100 concurrent calls, the first question I'd try to answer is whether your EJB scales in a linear fashin - 10 threads may be enough here.

Comment: @Peter: I think it's about throughput (stress, load test, etc.).

Comment: @home, That is the most likely explanation. In which case he need multiple clients not threads as he is likely to find that his framework/system cannot have more than a few concurrent requests at once. It could be as small as 2-4. Testing a system in ways that will never occur isn't very useful.

Comment: @Chin: As Peter said, you should clarify the scope of your test. What do you want to achieve with your test (performance, throughput, scalability)?

Comment: @home i guess for this case it is throughput i would like to test, to see if this ejb is able to substain an x number of concurrent call / access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 4 cores which support hyper threading, you can only actually load 8 threads at once.  You can start more threads than this, however only 8 can be active at any one time.  This is a limitation of the hardware you are using.

I very much doubt you need to run 10K or 100K threads to test any system.  Most systems can be saturated with work with just one thread (or a very small number) and I suspect your EJB is no exception.

You cannot test a method is thread safe via brute force testing.  You can only determine this by reading the code.

You might find this article interesting [Java: What is the limit to the number of threads you can create?](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-what-is-limit-to-number-of-threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

100000 is definitely too much. If your thread is CPU intensive then only 1 thread per CPU/core should be enough. On the other hand, if your thread is not CPU intensive, you can have more than 1 thread per CPU/core. You should conduct more test to find out the optimum number of thread.